# RuntimeWarning: unknown response content type 'text/html' returning raw response

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, sparql, sparqlwrapper

I tried to use apache jena fuseki in my python code so I found this:
https://sparqlwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/main.html

I followed the first example and here is my code:

```
pip install sparqlwrapper
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON
sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://localhost:3030/dataset.html")
sparql.setQuery("""
    PREFIX ahpo: <http://e-hp.ahp-numerique.fr/ahpo#>
    PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
    SELECT ?letter ?corres ?writingDate
    WHERE {
    ?letter ahpo:sentBy <http://henripoincare.fr/api/items/843>
    ?letter ahpo:sentTo ?y
    ?y dcterms:title ?corres
    ?letter ahpo:writingDate ?writingDate
    ?letter ahpo:citeName <http://henripoincare.fr/api/items/333> }  
    LIMIT 50                                                             
""")
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
results = sparql.query().convert()
```

And I got this Error:
/home/issam/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/SPARQLWrapper/Wrapper.py:1346: RuntimeWarning: unknown response content type 'text/html' returning raw response...
warnings.warn("unknown response content type '%s' returning raw response..." %(ct), RuntimeWarning)

Any solutions ?

Thanks

Comment: @JacquesGaudin
Hey, I tried it now, and I'm getting the same error: 

/home/issam/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/SPARQLWrapper/Wrapper.py:1346: RuntimeWarning: unknown response content type 'text/html' returning raw response...
  warnings.warn("unknown response content type '%s' returning raw response..." %(ct), RuntimeWarning)

Comment: Then it's probably trying to tell you that `dataset.html` is a plain text file, when it expects one of the supported datatypes, i.e. JSON, XML, etc. If you have control over the server, try and server the data as an XML file, the warning should disappear.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin
it's apache jena fuseki, I can't control over the server to serve data as XML file

Comment: Could you post your server endpoint configuration? I think the issue lies there.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin
this is apache jena fuseki : https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/

I just downloaded it and uploaded my data (.ttl format) to it, when I run my server I can write sparql queries and get result with json and xml (but I can't control data format when sending to sparqlwrapper)

Comment: Ok. then shouldn't your queries be directed to `http://localhost:3030/ds/data`?

Comment: `http://localhost:3030/dataset.html` is clearly the wrong URL which just points to some HTML document but not to the SPARQL service of Fuseki - don't mix up a web interface with the underyling SPARQL HTTP URL. Please check the Fuseki docs and then just use `http://localhost:3030/ds/sparql`

Comment: @JacquesGaudin and UninformedUser
Thanks a lot for your help the problem was in the link I should use http://localhost:3030/ds/sparql rather than http://localhost:3030/dataset.html

Answer (score 0):

The answer has been already given in the comments under the question, but let me generalize the solution a bit. According to the [nice presentation about triple stores](http://www.linkedbuildingdata.net/ldac2019/summerschool/files/07_Bonduel_triplestores_SPARQL_endpoints.pdf), Apache Jena Fuseki uses the following endpoint URLs:

```
# Read (GET/POST):
http://localhost:3030/MyDB/query
http://localhost:3030/MyDB/sparql

# Update (POST):
http://localhost:3030/MyDB/update
```

You can always check what your current setup provides on Fuseki's web GUI:

- Open http://localhost:3030/ in your browser and navigate to the `Info` page of your dataset.
- **Available services** and their exact URLs should be listed there.

(*The above is true at least for Apache Jena Fuseki 4.2 or 4.4*)